# Logging in Django with raven and sentry

Tags: django, sentry, raven

I may be a bit late on the train, but I wanted to use Sentry and Raven for logging in Django.

I set up sentry and raven to the point, where I ran the test for raven and it works.

So now I want to send my debug messages over to sentry, but how would I do this?

settings.py

```
RAVEN_CONFIG = {
    'dsn': 'http://code4@mydomain:9000/2',
    # If you are using git, you can also automatically configure the
    # release based on the git info.
    'release': raven.fetch_git_sha(BASE_DIR),
}

LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(module)s %(process)d %(thread)d %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'sentry': {
            'level': 'WARNING',
            'class': 'raven.contrib.django.raven_compat.handlers.SentryHandler',
        },
        'console': {
            'level': 'WARNING',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'verbose'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['sentry'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'raven': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'handlers': ['sentry'],
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'sentry.errors': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'handlers': ['sentry'],
            'propagate': False,
        },
    }
}
```

view.py

```
import logger
from raven.contrib.django.models import get_client


client = get_client()
client.captureException()

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)



def my_view(request):

   [...]
    logger.error('There was some crazy error', exc_info=True, extra={
    # Optionally pass a request and we'll grab any information we can
    'request': request,
    })
    [...]
```

At this point it just logs errors and exceptions but wont send me this error message...

How is the right way to use raven and sentry? The docs are totaly not helping and my google foo left me also. Any tips or helpfull tutorials?

Comment: Generally DEBUG logging is not useful in Sentry. We push back pretty heavily when someone says they want this, because usually they misunderstand how Sentry works. If you're fine w/ the limitations of Sentry, or you have a non-standard case where you use the DEBUG level for actually important error-type data, then this is ok.

Comment: Ok thanks for the clarification - I tried to follow https://docs.getsentry.com/hosted/clients/python/integrations/django/ and while exception handling worked really nice out of the box the integration with logging didn't worked with the setup - It is totally possible that I misunderstood the section and / or it is not the main usease but I thought it would be nice if the config in the config turned out working for me

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have 3 loggers defined: `django`, `raven` and `sentry.errors`. When you call `logging.getLogger(__name__)` you actually create a "throw-away" one, because your `___name__` doesn't match any of above.

You should either use the `raven` logger...

```
logger = logging.getLogger('raven')
logger.debug('Hola!')
```

...or setup your own:

```
LOGGING = {
    # ...
    'loggers': {
        # ...
        'yourapp': {
            'level': 'debug',
            'handlers': ['sentry'],
            'propagate': False,
        },
    }
}
```

and then in `yourapp/views.py`:

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.debug('Hola!')
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer - but somehow it still doens't work I et the logger to 'raven' but it dosn't get its message to sentry

Comment: Sorry, but the above config works just fine in my environment. I've put together a gist just from the real code, take a look: https://gist.github.com/alexmorozov/b1fd5a8cd292b64998c3 . Maybe your settings somehow haven't got reloaded?

Comment: Fantastic! Let's sort out what was the reason to make the answer complete. Was it the INSTALLED_APPS addition or a `root` section in `LOGGING`?

Comment: I think it was the section in the LOGGING and the name in getLogger, than can it take some time till the message is transfered to sentry. Than the loglevel must be at least has high as the level specified at the handler. And nothing of this is mentioned in the docs (or I didn't found it)